# i am failing to set intel as disassembly flavour in gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb, intel, symbol-table

i want to set disassembly flavour to intel ........
i tried the following...............................

**$ gdb -q**

**/root/.gdbinit:1: Error in sourced command file:**

**No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.**

**(gdb) set disassembly-flavour intel**

**No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.**

i have entered set "disassembly-flavour intel" in file ~/.gdbinit

**> echo "set disassembly-flavour intel" > ~/.gdbinit**

Answer (score 6):

You made a mistake in the command. You should have written flavor. Instead you wrote flavour.

```
(gdb) help set disassembly-flavor
Set the disassembly flavor.
The valid values are "att" and "intel", and the default value is "att".
```

And this is an example:

```
>gdb -q
(gdb) show disassembly-flavor
The disassembly flavor is "att".
(gdb) set disassembly-flavor intel
(gdb) show disassembly-flavor
The disassembly flavor is "intel".
(gdb)
```

Comment: Anyone knows why I'm getting: 'No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.' trying to run this?

Comment: @IgorVoltaic , You're getting that error being there is a mistype in your command. Found this through my own experience.